# Mocking Laravel controller dependency

Tags: php, unit-testing, laravel, phpunit

In my Laravel app I have a controller with a method to show a particular resource. E.g. say the url is `/widgets/26` My controller method might work like so:

```
Class WidgetsController {
    protected $widgets;

    public function __construct(WidgetsRepository $widgets)
    {
        $this->widgets = $widgets;
    }

    public function show($id)
    {
        $widget = $this->widgets->find($id);

        return view('widgets.show')->with(compact('widget'));
    }
}
```

As we can see my `WidgetsController` has a `WidgetsRepository` dependency. In a unit test for the `show` method, how can I mock this dependency so that I don't actually have to call the repository and instead just return a hard-coded `widget`?

Unit test start:

```
function test_it_shows_a_single_widget()
{
    // how can I tell the WidgetsController to be instaniated with a mocked WidgetRepository?
    $response = $this->action('GET', 'WidgetsController@show', ['id' => 1]);

    // somehow mock the call to the repository's `find()` method and give a hard-coded return value
    // continue with assertions
}
```

Answer (score 24):

You can mock the repository class and load it into the IoC container.

So when Laravel gets to your controller, it will find it *already* in there and will resolve your mock instead of instantiating a new one.

```
function test_it_shows_a_single_widget()
{
    // mock the repository
    $repository = Mockery::mock(WidgetRepository::class);
    $repository->shouldReceive('find')
        ->with(1)
        ->once()
        ->andReturn(new Widget([]));

    // load the mock into the IoC container
    $this->app->instance(WidgetRepository::class, $repository);

    // when making your call, your controller will use your mock
    $response = $this->action('GET', 'WidgetsController@show', ['id' => 1]);

    // continue with assertions
    // ...
}
```

*A similar setup has been tested and working fine in Laravel 5.3.21.*

Answer (score 3):

There was a similar question on Laracasts. The person had something like this ( https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/mockery-error?page=1 ) :

```php
public function testMe()
{
    // Arrange
    $classContext = Mockery::mock('\FullNamespace\To\Class');
    $classContext->shouldReceive('id')->andReturn(99);
    $resources = new ResourcesRepo($classContext);

    // Act

   // Assert
}
```

You could however put this as well on the setUp method if using PHPUnit method ( http://docs.mockery.io/en/latest/reference/phpunit_integration.html ).

Hope this is helpful.